# Insert an image at the end of the first page of the document

Tags: graphics

I have to include at the first page of the document a specific image.

How is it possible to add it only at the end of the first page of the document?

Comment: `\includegraphics{image}  \clearpage` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank but it makes it to go to the end of the page?

Comment: you can use `\vfill` before it for example. Is this part of a titlepage design? a `\end{titlepage}` usually has a forced page break so `\clearpage` would not be necessary.